# How to display data the corresponds to other data MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, urlencode

My working PHP script connects to my database fetches the data, and then puts it into a table like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //mysql_fetch_array bring back an object, in this case the $result of the mysql query and puts it into a variable $row
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align='center'><img height='100' width='100' src=\"" . $row['picturepath'] . "\" /></td>"; //here I can use the results and call out which column I want from my database

  echo '<td align="center">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td align="center"><input type="button" value="More Info" onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['description']) .' \';" /></td>';


  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['price'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='Add to Order' onclick=''> </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

echo "<table width=\"1024\" align=\"center\" >";
    echo "<tr height=\"50\"></tr>";
```

The "More Info" button links to a separate php script, more_info.php, where the description is read onto the page for that specific item. I wanted to also display the image that corresponds to that item, and have been having trouble doing so.

**What I have tried.**

I have modified the above code to display:

```
more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['description']) . urlencode($row['picturepath']) . '\';" /></td>';
```

which then pulls the correct information in, however it literally pulls in the filename of the image, rather than the actual picture.

**Goal**

I'd like to have the "More Info" link, pull the description and image of the item the user clicks 'more info' on, and dump both into "more_info.php". Would I have to use $_POST in this scenario? Or maybe on the more_info.php run a query where the picturepath is displayed only if it matches the name of the item? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

tough to tell whats going on in more_info.php without seeing the code, but you need a way to differentiate the 2 fields (description, picturepath) in that php script.  for the url use something like:

```
$url = "more_info.php?start=" . urlencode($row['description']) . "&path=" . urlencode($row['picturepath']);
```

use $url string in your onclick:

```
... onclick="window.location=\'$url\'" ...
```

then in the more_info.php use $_GET to retrieve the 2 parameters (start, path) passed as part of the URL:

```
if(isset($_GET['start']) && isset($_GET['path'])){
    $description = $_GET['start'];
    $picturepath = $_GET['path'];
    echo "Description: $description <img src=\"$picturepath\"/>";
}
```

Not sure if this helps/was what you were looking for.  if not provide the more_info.php and it's current output.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the 'description' and 'picturepath' are names of columns that are in my database. I don't think this will work.

Comment: I understand, but as far as your script is concerned 'description' and 'picturepath' are keys to elements in the array $row.  Is your goal not to pass the value in the elements to another script via the URL? The only change I have made is to separate the data into 2 different parameters (start, path) using the '&' in the URL: *.php?param=value&foo=bar. Their names are trivial as long as your script knows what to expect. Perhaps I don't understand the original question...